Show $ I(k):=\lim _{R \rightarrow+\infty} \int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{i k x}}{1+|x|} d x $ exists
I'm trying to solve this problem from a past Stanford qual, but I'm a bit stuck. (EDIT: I have now solved the problem. See the solution below.)

Show that for each $k \in \mathbb{R} \backslash\{0\}$ the limit
$$
I(k):=\lim _{R \rightarrow+\infty} \int_{-R}^R \frac{e^{i k x}}{1+|x|} d x
$$
exists, and find all $m \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim _{k \rightarrow 0}|k|^m I(k)=0$.

This looks like the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{1+|x|}$, but I'm not sure what to do with this fact. If I expand $e^{ikx}$, I get
$$\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{-R}^R\frac{e^{ikx}}{1 + |x|}dx =\lim_{R\to\infty}\left[\int_{-R}^R\frac{\cos(kx)}{1 + |x|}dx + i\int_{-R}^R\frac{\sin(kx)}{1 + |x|}dx \right]$$
The imaginary part is zero because $\frac{1}{1+|x|}$ is even and $\sin(kx)$ is odd over a symmetric domain. Therefore we just have to worry about
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^R\frac{\cos(kx)}{1 + |x|}dx=\lim_{R\to\infty}2\int_0^R\frac{\cos(kx)}{1+x}dx$$
now integrating by parts, we may set $u=\frac{1}{1+x}$ so that $du=\frac{-1}{(1+x)^2}dx$ and $v=\frac{1}{k}\sin(kx)$ and $dv=\sin(kx)dx$. Usng integration by parts
$$2\int_0^R \frac{\cos(kx)}{1+x}dx = \left.\frac{2}{k}\frac{\sin(kx)}{1+x}\right|_0^R-2\int_0^R \frac{-1}{k(1+x)^2}\sin(kx)dx.$$
Now $$\left|\int_0^R \frac{\sin(kx)}{(1+x)^2}dx\right|\leq \int_0^R\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}dx=\left.\frac{-1}{1+x}\right|_0^R= \frac{-1}{1+R} + 1$$
Therefore, we get that the integral converges absolutely, so the limit exists.
Now using the bound
$-\frac{2}{|k|}\leq I(k)\leq \frac{2}{\left|k\right|}$ we get that $-2|k|^{m-1}\leq |k|^mI(k)\leq 2|k|^{m-1}$ so $
\lim _{k \rightarrow 0}|k|^m I(k)=0
$ if $m> 1$ by the squeeze theorem.
Now when $m < 1$, then since $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$, we get
$$\lim_{k\to 0}|k|^{m}I(x) =\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{2|k|^{m}}{k} \int_0^R \frac{\sin(kx)}{1 + |x|}dx=\lim_{k\to 0}2|k|^{m-1} \int_0^R \frac{\sin(kx)}{1 + |x|}dx = \infty$$
and when $m=1$, we have
$$\lim_{k\to 0}|k|^{m}I(x) =\lim_{k\to 0} \int_0^R \frac{\sin(kx)}{1 + |x|}dx\neq 0.$$

Integrate by parts now. This allows you to trade in the oscillatory nature for some decay in the integrand plus an oscillating boundary term (different example but similar idea).

@peek-a-boo Ah thank you! I tried this but I set my $u$ and $dv$ in the opposite way.

@peek-a-boo Should I attempt to directly evaluate this integral now?

The question only asks to show the limit exists…

Absolute convergence of an integral implies convergence.

@peek-a-boo Great! And last question, what can I do about the $m=1$ case?

Write out what $I(k)$ is equal to after all your calculations and taking the limit.

@peek-a-boo Ok solved the question thank you so much!!

Your argument is still flawed. Especially the $m<1$ case and also the $m=1$ case is more subtle than that.

@peek-a-boo what's wrong with the $m<1$ case?

For $m<1$ you simply have that the two bounds approach $\infty$, but that says nothing about what happens in the middle. This is like a false squeeze theorem.

You are correct in proving the convergence, but not the part about $m$.
We have, integrating by parts twice,
\begin{align}
\frac{I(k)}2&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(kx)}{1+x}\mathrm{d}x
=\frac1k\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}(\sin(kx))}{1+x}
=\frac1k\left.\frac{\sin(kx)}{1+x}\right|_0^\infty
+\frac1k\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(kx)\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x)^2}
\\ &
=\frac1k\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(kx)\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x)^2}
=-\frac1{k^2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}(\cos(kx))}{(1+x)^2}
\\ &
=-\frac1{k^2}\left.\frac{\cos(kx)}{(1+x)^2}\right|_0^\infty
-\frac1{k^2}\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(kx)\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x)^3}
=\frac1{k^2}\left(1+O(1)\right)
\end{align}
so $I(k)|k|^m\to 0$ whenever $m<2$.
Note that in fact you can keep continuing the integration by parts to get even more precise expansion:
$$
\frac{I(k)}2=\frac{1}{k^2}-\frac{6}{k^4}+\frac{120}{k^6}+\dots
$$

Thank you this is great! Why couldn’t we have stopped at the first by parts?

Actually, you are correct! That would be enough for your purpose. The next line would be needed only should you want to prove $I(k)k^2\to 2$.

Does this mean that $I(k)|k|^m \to 0$ when $m> 1$?

No, it means $\lim_{k\to\infty} I(k)|k|^m= 0$ when $m<2$, $\lim_{k\to\infty} I(k)|k|^m= \infty$ when $m>2$, and $\lim_{k\to\infty} I(k)|k|^2= 2$.
